# How to open an intent category with a deeplink with navigation components

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to open the app's additional settings screen from `android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES`.

I have a single activity pattern and the manifest looks like this:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The navigation graph entry of the Settings screen looks like this.

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/settings">
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLinkToSettingsFragment"
            app:uri="myapp://screen/settings" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLinkToSettingsFragment2"
            app:action="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES"
            app:uri="myapp://screen/settings" />
```

I know `android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES` is a category and not an action. Is it somehow possible to launch the additional settings screen while using navigation components?